# featured post slider not working

Tags: jquery, slider, wordpress, image-gallery

My blog link is:

http://guruschool.org/angelsschool/

Initially slider was working. But as I wanted to have image gallery, I have installed WP EASY GALLERY plugin.

After installing WP EASY GALLERY plugin my slider stops working. As now navigation of my slider is not working also I am getting below error..

```
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'superfish'  
Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'cycle'
```

Kindly suggest me some solutions as I want to have image gallery as well so don't want to delete this plugin...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it by editing my gallery plugin..

I have just removed the line which loads jquery files to document header such that it will not conflict with existing slider files..

Now its working fine for me...

Comment: Hi, I'm experiencing exactly the same problem (I have a site based on EducationWeb theme as yours). Can you detail exactly how you solved the problem? Thanks a lot

Answer (score 0):

Seems like your scripts are non loaded.

Comment: may be.. but i think its because of conflict as the plugin also uses jquery and slider also uses the jquery.. so just searcching how should i keep the both..

Answer (score 0):

Yes Confliction of Jquery is the problem .I have faced the same type of conflicts earlier Try to use Next-gen gallery instead of the gallery you are using that gallery will also give you better options Even you can use Lightbox functionality there by Just Intalling LightBox Plus Plugin and by setting options in Gallery options to Lightbox..